# Java: How can I add numbers in an If Statement (explanation in the post)

Tags: java, if-statement, variables, addition

I am doing some homework for university.

I have to iterate a string over an int array to decode matching signs.

I need your help with the following problem:

This is my Code right now:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            String s = "| || |  ||||  |||| || || | ||| || ||";

            int result = 0;
            int[] num = {0, 1, 2, 4, 7};
            String over = "";
            String[] parts = s.split("(?<=\\G.{6})");
            for(int i=0; i<parts.length; i++) {
              parts[i] = parts[i].substring(0, 5);
              over = parts[i];
              for(int j = 0; j < num.length; j++) {
                  if(over.charAt(j) == ' ') {
                      result = num[j];

                  }                   
              }
              System.out.println(result);
}



}
```

Output is: 711424 but I need it to be 811424.

```
for(int j = 0; j < num.length; j++) {
                  if(over.charAt(j) == ' ') {
                      result = num[j];
```

Here is my problem I think. My Variable "result" does not add the first result an the next one.
I hope you see what I mean. I've tried various things, but cannot seem to get it done without screwing the rest of the numbers up.

Thank you

For clarification: This is the math behind the decoding:

[Its in German, sorry for that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnG1m.png)

Comment: "*result does not add the first result an the next one*" did you try `result = result + num[j]`?

Comment: Sorry, this isn't very clear.  Why do you think the output should be 811424?

Comment: Yes, but this screws the other numbers up. My Code doesn't add the numbers of the num array together in the result, whenever there's 2 matches in one part. I hope this makes sense

Comment: The given String is a coded ZIP Code. Its a thing in Germany to have this coded. Heres some info (in German, sorry for that) https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zielcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an intermediate variable to calculate your final result for the loop should do the trick.

This worked perfectly for me!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            String s = "| || |  ||||  |||| || || | ||| || ||";

            int result = 0;
            int[] num = {0, 1, 2, 4, 7};
            String over = "";
            String[] parts = s.split("(?<=\\G.{6})");
            for(int i=0; i<parts.length; i++) {
              parts[i] = parts[i].substring(0, 5);
              over = parts[i];
              int intermediateResult = 0;
              for(int j = 0; j < num.length; j++) {
                  if(over.charAt(j) == ' ') {
                      intermediateResult += num[j];

                  }                   
              }
              result = intermediateResult;
              System.out.println(result);
       }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Code with redundant variables removed.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            String s = "| || |  ||||  |||| || || | ||| || ||";

            int[] num = {0, 1, 2, 4, 7};
            String[] parts = s.split("(?<=\\G.{6})");
            for(int i=0; i<parts.length; i++) {
              parts[i] = parts[i].substring(0, 5);
              int result = 0;
              for(int j = 0; j < num.length; j++) {
                  if(parts[i].charAt(j) == ' ') {
                      result += num[j];

                  }                   
              }
              System.out.println(result);
       }
}
```

Comment: that's way too many useless intermediate variables (over, intermediateResult, maybe more), but I confirm the algorithm fix

Comment: I wasn't going for a code cleanup in this answer anyways. But I do agree to your point!

Answer (score 0):

As noted above, you just forgot to sum the 4 useful parts of the encoded value, as in 8 = 1+7;

But more notes about the code:

if you use `int[] num = {0, 1, 2, 4, 7, 0};` you don't even need to split the string s, assuming it always has multiples of 6 elements. You then can use a simple while or for loop of s's full length (especially if the length of s is constant, or it can be filled up to be of constant length, in case you may have 5 or 6 digits instead of always 6).
In that loop you can either use the index `i%6` or keep another index j going back to 0 every times it reaches 6, but it should be equivalent for speed. You need that index to println the digit, reset the intermediate sum to 0, and in real life to sum it the the total postal code before that reset.

But even better, you could use `int[] num = {0, 100000, 200000, 400000, 700000, 0, 0, 10000, 20000, 40000, 70000, 0, 0, 1000, 2000, 4000, 7000, 0, 0, 100, 200, 400, 700, 0, 0, 10, 20, 40, 70, 0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 7, 0};` and then all you need to compute is the "cross product" between s and num. Which is a very simple `while ... if(charAt(i) == ' ') ...` or can even become a call to the real cross product function if you encode s directly as 01001011000011... also in an array (with 0='|', 1=' ').